# MongoDB.Driver.Linq.ExpressionNotSupportedException

Tags: c#, mongodb

Everything was working okay with the previous version of MongoDb driver version 2.17.1   and now I have upgrade my MongoDb driver to lastest version 2.19.1 and now I get this error:  'Expression not supported: Convert(o.DataStatusID) because conversion to System.Nullable`1[System.Int32] is not supported

```
Data class:
public byte? DataStatusID {get; set;}

LoadData():
Collection.FindSync<Data>(o => o.DataStatusID == 1)
```

how to get around this error?

Comment: Did you update the database as well ?

Comment: No, I didn't update my database

Comment: Well that could be the issue, driver is too new compared to the DB

Answer (score 3):

Besides a possible version mismatch between driver and engine (which really should not allow a connection at all in case of any incompatibility IMO), there is the following connection setting that allows you to chose between three different versions of the MongoDb LINQ Provider:

```
var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";
var clientSettings = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString(connectionString);
clientSettings.LinqProvider = LinqProvider.V3;
var client = new MongoClient(clientSettings);
```

Recently (2023-10), V2 was still their default. A problem similar to, but not identical with, your observation was solved by setting this to V3. Since then, V3 now appears to be the default (as of driver version 2.19) and V1 is gone for good.

Your mileage may vary, I actually had it both ways around in production: for an expression of the form

`lambda.get_Item("field")`

towards a MongoDb 7.0 and with the C# Driver version 2.19.2 I had to **downgrade** to V2 to make it work:

```
clientSettings.LinqProvider = LinqProvider.V2;
```

Documentation:
https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.18/reference/driver/crud/linq3/

Comment: Is there a solution to this which doesn't involve downgrading?

Comment: yes, it requires to change any legacy BSON (aggregation pipeline definitions constructed in code and so on) to use only the form supported by V3 as per the docs. In the case of OP, this would mean to remove the nullability `?` on the `DataStatusID` property, or separating the query into two branches, one for returning documents where the field is null and another one for the byte matching.